# Why is "this" being implicitly passed as a parameter whenever trying to invoke a constructor or a method?

Tags: java, oop

Consider this block of java code

```
    Public class MyClass {
       public void method(int a) {
            doSometing() ;
       }
      Public static void main(String[] args) {
          MyClass obj = new MyClass() ;
          int a = 0 ;
          obj.method(a) ; 
     }
    }
```

Apparently in java , whenever trying to invoke a constructor or a method it turns out that there is actually another value being implicitly 
passed by Java other than the explicit one passed by the Developer , which is "this" and I am familiar with the notion of "this" keyword in java but I think it is redundant for "this" to be passed to the method or the constructor implicitly if ive already declared which object this method belongs to, so why would the keyword "this" has to be passed ? , So in the example above Ive declared a class "MyClass" and a method in that class "method" with a return type of "void" then in the main function im declaring a new instance of that class "obj" and calling the method "method" passing the variable "a" as a parameter , so what is actually happening behind the scenes that when declaring a new instance of a class and invoking it`s constructor there is actually a parameter being passed implicitly which is the "this" keyword , so thats what it really looks like behind the scenes :

```
MyClass obj = new MyClass(this) ;
```

and the same thing applies when invoking the method :

```
obj.method(this,a) ;
```

Thats it , so please can anyone help me with that cuz im tryna learn java and I need to make sure that everything`s clear to me before I proceed any further to Advanced Topics

Thank you

Comment: Why dont you give an examole scenario?

Comment: What do you mean this is being passed as parameter? you mean obj.method(par, this) is how JVM treats this method? Where did you read that "this" is passed as another parameter? I think you misread whatever it is. The material you read might be telling this.obj.method(par);

Comment: This seems to be a Python concept than Java.

Comment: `this ` is the instance of a class, not just the class - it holds the values of the given instance fields, just declaring the class of a method is not enough. The method needs access to the actual field values of the given instance.

Comment: If you're seeing `this` being explicitly passed, that's... weird.  In non-static methods, `this` is a "magic" variable that refers to the current object.

Comment: You absolutely need to show an *actual example*, not nonsense code. This could mean a number of different things, most of which usually reduce to "it's not actually a parameter".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the most direct way to understand *why* you need to implicitly pass the `this` reference to every non-static function you call is to show you how such a function call works 'under the hood'.

Let's take a simple example like

```
class Test {
    public void foo(int arg) {}
    public static void bar(int arg) {}
    public void baz() {
        foo(1);
        bar(2);
    }
}
```

Now what is the difference between `foo` and `bar`?
The non-static function `foo` gets executed in the context of an object, while the static `bar` doesn't have such a context. That means that `foo` would be able to read and write any fields within that object, `bar` would not.

While Java as a language knows about the context of any function you call, the Java Virtual Machine (JVM) that actually executes the code does not directly differentiate between static and non-static functions and does not know any call contexts.
(Yes, this is a bit of a semantics question, since it differentiates between static and dynamic binding which is mostly the same as static/non-static functions)

So when you call a non-static method, the call context (i.e. the object on which the method is called) needs to be provided as an implicit parameter, which is called `this`.

The JVM bytecode for the example above is then the following:

```
public void baz();
Code:
   0: aload_0           // Push 'this' as the first parameter onto the stack
   1: iconst_1          // Push 1 as the second parameter onto the stack
   2: invokevirtual #2  // Call 'foo'
   5: iconst_2          // Push 2 as the first parameter onto the stack
   6: invokestatic  #3  // Call 'bar'
   9: return
```

You see that for a static function, you only push the parameter onto the stack (which is then popped by the subsequent invoke), for non-static functions, you first push `this` onto the stack, which was also the first argument of the `baz` function call (`aload` stands for *argument load*)

Answer (score 4):

I believe what you are looking for is: All(?) OO programming languages are implemented by passing "this" as a parameter to every function contained in a class.  The differences in the languages are how that' functionality is implemented.

In Python functions are just defined as functions and you pass "this" as the first parameter.

Most other OO languages hide "this" when they pass it, but it's still there--it has to be.  You could think of the passing of "this" as the difference between a method and a function.

In java if you want a function instead of a method, declare it static and then "this" shouldn't be passed.